# Migrating data when adding one-to-one relationship in EF Core?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, .net-core, entity-framework-core

After adding a new one-to-one relation to one of my table I cannot figure out how to add default data for existing rows in my database.

My database basically looked like this before upgrade:

```
-- Team --
  Name: TEXT

-- History --
  Id: INT
```

... where History is has foreign keys pointed to it from other unrelated tables.

In my upgrade I basically want a Team to have a single History so my new db looks like:

```
-- Team --
  Name: TEXT
  HistoryId: INT

-- History --
  Id: INT
```

My problem now, however is that I have existing Teams in my DB and they need to have unique History rows to point to, so I somehow need to create a new history row for each existing Team.

I tried to manually add the entries in the Up-method in my migration, but since my models don't match the existing schema, this fails.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: 0);

    using (var db = new XMDBContext())
    {
        foreach (var team in db.Team)
            team.History = new XMHistory();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Team_HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        column: "HistoryId",
        unique: true);

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Team_History_HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        column: "HistoryId",
        principalTable: "History",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately currently EF Core does not support seeding data from migration. The issue is tracked in their repository as [#629 - Seed Data](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/629).

The only solution I see currently is using the old good SQL through [`MigrationBuilder.Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_Sql_System_String_System_Boolean_) method. Unfortunately there is no access to the db provider services, so the next applies to SQL Server (although I've tried to use only standard SQL commands).

Let the original model was as follows:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

After adding FK from `Team` to `History` it becomes:

```
public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int HistoryId { get; set; }
    public History History { get; set; }
}
```

The auto generated migration is:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
        name: "HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        nullable: false,
        defaultValue: 0);

    migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
        name: "IX_Team_HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        column: "HistoryId");

    migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        name: "FK_Team_History_HistoryId",
        table: "Team",
        column: "HistoryId",
        principalTable: "History",
        principalColumn: "Id",
        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

Now, before `CreateIndex` command we manually insert the following:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "TeamId",
    table: "History",
    nullable: true);

migrationBuilder.Sql(@"insert into History (TeamId) select Id from Team");

migrationBuilder.Sql(@"update Team set HistoryId = (select Id from History where TeamId = Team.Id)");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "TeamId",
    table: "History");
```

The idea is simple. We create a temporary nullable column `TeamId` in the `History` table, insert a new record with corresponding `TeamId` for each record in `Team` table, then update the `HistoryId` column in the `Team` table using the `TeamId` column from the `History` table as a key, and finally delete the temporary column.

At this point the data transformation is complete and the FK constraint can be created.

<del>Far from good practices, but can be used as workaround.</del>

**Edit:** After [Gert Arnold's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811193/migrating-data-when-adding-one-to-one-relationship-in-ef-core/42867561#comment72849990_42867561), looks like using SQL blocks is the right way to go. The only thing that concerns me is how to write database agnostic and/or specific SQLs. Of course the problem does not exist if one is targeting a single specific database type. Anyway, if there is a need to handle different database types, one can always use standard SQL commands supported by all target databases combined with specific `if` blocks based on [`MigrationBuilder.ActiveProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_ActiveProvider) property.

Comment: Looks good Ivan! And I think it's the only way to go. Even if there was a Seed method it wouldn't have helped because it doesn't run *during* database upgrade. This scenario always requires some intermediary database state because you can't add a required FK to something that isn't there yet.

Comment: @GertArnold I guess you are right. I was thinking of splitting the migration on two parts, like add nullable property only to the model, generate migration, seed (populate the field with data), then change nullable to non nullable and add navigation property to the model, generate second migration. All this if there is `Seed` method running at the end of each migration. But now I'm not sure it's possible at all, because the entities will not be the same during the migration.

Comment: ... So may be SQL is the way, just wish to have some info/helpers (like `ISqlGenerationHelper` used in `MigrationSqlGenerator`) in order to write db agnostic SQL. Or a way to hook directly in `MigrationSqlBuilder`. Because all we have currently is `MigrationBuilder.ActiveProvider` string (which of course is better than nothing:).

Comment: I think it will always be a problem that there is a phase in the upgrade process where none of the entities (old or new) represents the database table (`History` with `TeamId`), so there's nothing that can be used as a mapped entity (for generating native SQL). And changing the context twice + add migration and seeding seems a bit contrived.

Comment: @Gert Indeed. So the old school way only then :) With some SQL build helpers :)