# Execute custom SQL script as part of Entity Framework migration

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have been using the standard add-migration approach to updating my aspnet core database on Entity Framework.  I now have to move two "image" columns into a new table (and their image data), remove the columns from the original table, and set up a foreign key relationship between the old and new tables.  I have a working SQL script to do all this.

**How can I execute this sql script as part of a normal EF migration, AND make sure subsequent add-migration changes will reflect the changes that my sql script will do (adding new table/columns, removing image columns from original table)?**

I've seen a few references to SqlFile and deriving from DbMigration, but nothing that fits my scenario nicely.  I am using EF Core, aspnet core 2.0.

Comment: Make the model modifications, generate the migration, then edit the `Up` method of the generated migration and use [`Sql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_MigrationBuilder_Sql_System_String_System_Boolean_) method inside. Something similar to [Migrating data when adding one-to-one relationship in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811193/migrating-data-when-adding-one-to-one-relationship-in-ef-core/42867561#42867561)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Moving a populated, non-nullable column**

Get Entity Framework to create the base migration and then enhance the output.

Some example code that moves an `EmailAddress` field from `OldTable` to `NewTable` (MS SQL Server):

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
    name: "EmailAddress",
    table: "NewTable",
    defaultValue: "");

migrationBuilder.Sql("UPDATE NewTable SET NewTable.EmailAddress = OldTable.EmailAddress FROM NewTable JOIN OldTable ON NewTable.Id = OldTable.NewTableId");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "EmailAddress",
    table: "NewTable",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: "");

migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
    name: "EmailAddress",
    table: "OldTable");
```

Remember, this needs to happen for `Up()` and `Down()`, except `Down()` undoes the operation.

Answer (score 38):

You may edit created migration class (`Up` and `Down` methods) and include any SQL you want in correct place:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "MyExtraColumn",
        table: "MySuperTable");

    migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP DATABASE [master]"); // <<< Anything you want :)

    migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
        name: "MyExtraColumn2",
        table: "MySuperTable");
}
```

It's your responsibility do not "break" the database schema (in EntityFramework point of view) and to provide reliable `Down` script to be able to migrate up/down/up/down multiple times.

Also, don't forget to re-add SQLs again if you will remove migration and re-add it.

Comment: And, if you want the equivalent of `SqlFile()`, just use `Sql(File.ReadAllText("my.sql"))`.

Comment: "DROP DATABASE [master]" in code sample is brutal :)

Comment: I too like to live dangerously 

Comment: Just wait for Copilot to scrape this page and start recommending it :)